# Grails String to BigDecimal

Tags: grails

I can't figure out how to transform a String into a BigDecimal inside a Grails Application.

I'm doing:

```
person.salary = params.number
```

But I got a error.

```
*salary is a BigDecimal and params.number is always a string.
```

Comment: Did you try `params.number as BigDecimal`? (It's been a bit since I did that Groovy.)

Answer (score 4):

> I can't figure out how to transform a String into a BigDecimal inside
>   a Grails Application.

`BigDecimal` has a `String` constructor so one thing you could do is `new BigDecimal(params.number)`.

You have other options...

You could do `params.number as BigDecimal`.

You could use one of the type converting convenience methods like `params.double('number') as BigDecimal` or you could provide a default value like `params.double('number', 21.12) as BigDecimal)`.  Be aware that you could lose precision while converting to a `double` so if that is an issue, don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
person.salary = params.number.toBigDecimal()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want **number** parameter to be BigDecimal you can consider to the bind parameter with following method:

**Method 1: Bind as Controller Action's argument**

Instead of access by **params.number** you can add **number** parameter as below:

```
def anyAction(double number){
  ...
  person.salary = number
  ...
}
```

**Method 2: Data Binding with Domain object**

Create a domain

```
class SomeClass {
    BigDecimal number
}
```

Data binding in controller action

```
// will bind every parameters in params to an object dataBinding
def dataBinding = new SomeClass(params) 
person.salary = dataBinding.number // it number are BigDecimal
```

May be there are other way than this, but I hope it can help